# Using google protobuf with libraries in cmake on Windows, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have a CMake project with several sub-directories and library modules that eventually get built into client and server libraries, and those libraries are used from executable to test them. I am trying to use Google's protobuf library inside one of those libraries. I am creating my sub-library as follows:

```
include_directories(
    .
    ../rendering_backend
    ../shared
    ${MY_THIRDPARTY_DIR}/protobuf/include
)

add_library(Client STATIC
    client.cpp
    client.hpp
    ../common.hpp
    ../shared/protobufs/my_bufs.pb.cc
    ../shared/protobufs/my_bufs.pb.h
)

target_link_libraries(Client
    RenderingBackend
    ${MY_THIRDPARTY_DIR}/protobuf/lib/libprotobufd.lib
)
```

The executable is declared as follows:

```
add_executable(TEST_Client
    client_tester.cpp
    ../src/rendering_backend/rendering_backend.hpp)

target_link_libraries(TEST_Client Client)
```

All these files seem to be generating properly, but when I build, I get the following error (and many just like it):

```
libprotobufd.lib(zero_copy_stream_impl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in client_tester.obj
```

I have gone back to the protobuf solution and verified that all projects are set to use /MDd in their Runtime Library setting. It was generated following the guide at https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake.

I have seen many questions and answers about protobufs, but none seem to address this problem. I don't know what could be trying to build /MTd when everything is set to /MDd inside Visual Studio.

Assuming that this process would work if I were doing it correctly, I can only assume I'm doing something wrong. What is the intended way to do something like this?

[EDIT]
I was trying to use protobuf 3.0.0 here.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to rebuild the `install` target after you set `-Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF` and rebuilt the `protobuf` project? Also, you should use `find_package` instead of manually hardcoding the protobuf include dirs and libs.

Comment: So I tried using `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` -- I had to switch from protobuf 3 down to 2.6.1 -- and it's not finding my library. I tried setting `set(PROTOBUF_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER "[path-to-protobuf]" CACHE PATH "Protobuf Root")` but it [looks like](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake) maybe it doesn't even try reading that variable if it's already set? In any case, it's returning `PROTOBUF_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER-NOTFOUND` from `find_package`.

Comment: You need to set (or extend) `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with the directory you installed `Protobuf` to. That must be the directory `<dir>` which contains the config-module at `<dir>/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake`. Use `find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)` to avoid the built-in `FindProtobuf.cmake`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `find_package` to identify the correct paths, you must edit the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to search for libraries. This code allows it to find the path correctly, assuming that you have correctly set up `THIRDPARTY_DIR` and you downloaded the release version of protobuf (2.6.1 as of this writing):

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/protobuf-2.6.1
)
```

Protobuf3 can also be used but in addition to setting the install path in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, you must also supply the `CONFIG` argument to `find_package` as follows:

```
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

...assuming Protobuf is required.

In my case, I configured Protobuf 3.0.0 beta 2 to install to a folder "install" within its own directory:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/protobuf-3.0.0-beta-2/install
)

find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

(*Thanks to tamas.kenez for correcting me on this.*)

Note that I had to build the release library before `find_package(Protobuf)` would return without errors. I originally only build the debug libraries.

I also had to be cautious of which MSVC runtime I build with. Dynamic seems to be the default for most projects, but Protobuf3 builds with the static runtime unless you configure it to do otherwise (there's a checkbox if you're using the GUI). Linking static runtime libraries to dynamic runtime executables causes all kinds of linker problems and redefinitions, so be careful of that.

Lastly, CMake GUI seems to retain some information about directory structures until you reload the project (or possibly restart the program entirely); so I hit a snag in trying to change which version of protobuf I used when CMake kept finding a directory structure I had already deleted, even after clearing the whole build directory. (Solved by clearing the build directory and relaunching CMake GUI and reloading the base project.)

Comment: This advice is not correct. Protobuf3 does install a decent config module (to `lib/cmake/protobuf`) which is fully compatible with CMake's built-in FindProtobuf.cmake. So you can use find-package for Protobuf 3, too. You need to specify `CONFIG` to avoid the built-in module: `find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have updated this answer accordingly based on what worked for me after following your advice. Please let me know if I got anything else wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's ok. A related minor detail if you're interested: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is mostly to be set by the one who executes the cmake command (either on the command line or in cmake-gui). Changing CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not prohibited but it's unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git-subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) or [git-submodule](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/12/git-submodules/) to make [google protobuf sources](https://github.com/google/protobuf) part of your solution and build it with your project.

Add to your top-level CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory("third-party/protobuf/cmake")
include_directories("third-party/protobuf/src")
```

to get all protobuf targets.
Then you can add dependency to protobuf with

```
target_link_libraries(YourLibrary libprotobuf libprotobuf-lite libprotoc)
```

Hope this helps.