# How to install protobuf and link to cmake?

Tags: cmake, centos, protocol-buffers

I have been trying to do a build with cmake3 that involves using protobuf library version >=3.11. I think I correctly installed the compiler at least, since `protoc --version` returns `libprotoc 3.12.3` . However, the library does not seem to be properly linked cor cmake, just the compiler. If I try to do a cmake command, it warns that

```
Protobuf compiler version 3.12.3 doesn't match library version 2.5.0
```

which seems off since I installed protobuf 3.12 using the instructions here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src. This leads to errors when I try to do the make install when it doesn't recolonize headers introduced in later versions.

Protobuf 2.5.0 is the one that comes with `sudo yum install protobuf` and I need a more recent version for the cmake installation. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong so that cmake links the correct library version when compiling? I am on Centos 7 if that matters.

Comment: Did you set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point to the new Protobuf installation?

Comment: I only did `./configure make make check sudo make install sudo ldconfig` so unless that is part of those commands I don't think so

Comment: Perhaps, the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34738616/3987854) may help then.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit basic, but what file would I be editing for this solution? The cMakeLists file?

Comment: What I did when I used protobuf in Centos was `yum erase protobuf` to get rid of all protobuf2 libs and then made `cd <protobuf3-folder>/cmake; mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make; sudo make install`